# What's your favorite textbook on diatomic molecules?

Tags: atomic-physics, resource-recommendations, molecules

I'm a grad student in AMO physics. I'm looking for another textbook to read on diatomic molecules. Could you please recommend your favorites? I've read 'Spectra of Atoms and Molecules' by Bernath and that was good but was more general so lacked some details. Everyone says I need to read Brown and Carrington next (and I will) but I want to cover more than just the rotational spectroscopy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend "[Molecular Physics and Elements of Quantum Chemistry](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-662-08820-3)" by Haken and Wolf; covers both experiment and theory.

Covered theoretical topics include the theory of chemical bonding, the effect of electric and magnetic fields on molecules, and basic group theory. Several spectroscopic techniques are introduced, including Raman spectroscopy and nuclear magnetic and electron spin resonance. Practical applications such as molecular electronics are covered as well.

The book is relatively self-contained.